# how to get the id of buttons in a loop, so that when the button is pressed, a function takes the ids of each button

Tags: python, kivy

so, I am trying to use the id of buttons created in a loop to in a function with the following codes:

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    objff = mm.Show()
    objf = mm.Storenote()
    objf.tif(mm.DB.hod)
    for i in range(len(mm.Storenote.ht)):
        #size = dp(150)
        self.b = Button(text= (mm.Storenote.ht[i]), font_size = "25sp")
        #self.b.background_normal = ""
        self.b.background_color = 0,0,1,1
        self.b.ids =  {"id":mm.Storenote.nid[i]}
        self.b.size_hint=(1, None)
        self.b.size = (dp(370), dp(50))
        self.b.bind(on_press=self.clickk)
        self.ids.lpl.add_widget(self.b)

        #self.ids.lpl.add_widget(self.l[i])

def clickk(self, *args):
    print(self.b.ids.id)
    objff = mm.Show()
    objff.getter(self.b.ids.id)
    self.manager.current = "Readpage"
    self.remove_widget(self.b)
```

i want the clickk function in the on_press of the buttons in the loop to pick the ids of each button when the button is pressed. i want to use the ids of the button to retrieve data from the database but the self.b.ids.id in the clickk function is only picking the ids of the last button in the loop when i press any of the button and i understand cos the function is outside of the loop. what can i do to get each ids of each button in the loop every time a button is pressed

Comment: creating onClick function builder is a common pattern.
```py
def build_onClick(id):
  def onClick(event):
    // do something with id
  return onClick

self.b.bind(on_press=self.build_onClick(id))
```

Comment: Please could you explain this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code your reassign the same self.b at each iteration. Maybe you could try something like this

```py
self.buttons = list()
for i in range(len(mm.Storenote.ht)):
        b = Button(text= (mm.Storenote.ht[i]), font_size = "25sp")
        b.background_normal = ""
        b.background_color = 0,0,1,1
        b.ids =  {"id":mm.Storenote.nid[i]}
        b.size_hint=(1, None)
        b.size = (dp(370), dp(50))
        b.bind(on_press=self.clickk)
        self.buttons.append(b)
        self.ids.lpl.add_widget(b)
```

.. and use `self.buttons[index]` instead of `self.b`

Comment: I can't use the index of the button list in the clickky function because the click function is taking. Unique value from the mm.storenote.nid which I want to use the query the database

Comment: Then you could use a filter to retrieve your button by id ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating onClick callback builder is a common pattern to control an `onClick` in a loop.

```py
def build_onClick(self, something):
  def onClick(event):
    // do with something
  return onClick

self.b.bind(on_press=self.build_onClick(something))
```

In your case,

```py
...
        self.b.bind(on_press=self.build_clickk(self, self.b)
...
def build_clickk(self, b)
  def clickk(*args):
      print(b.ids.id)
      objff = mm.Show()
      objff.getter(b.ids.id)
      self.manager.current = "Readpage"
      self.remove_widget(b)
  return clickk
```

Comment: I don't know how to adapt my code to this. Please look at my clickk function, it is suppose to take each unique ids of the buttons on_press of each button. How does the button ids come in with this?

Comment: I added additional code. If it doesn't work perfectly, sorry. I haven't tested.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Accept this answer at your convenience.

Comment: If I want to remove the buttons created in the loop for when I leave the page that has the buttons. So that when I go back to the page it starts afresh with no buttons so it can show only the buttons without repeating them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but if you want to ask another question, you have to post another one.